# Google Play Paid App definition

Tags: android, subscription

I was unable to find clear reply on Google's help.

App is Free to use. It's absolutely useful. 
Also it's possible to buy subscription and get more in-app options.

Then is this app Paid or Free ?

As far as I understand it's paid.
But when I select Paid option in Developer Console, then it requests to provide price of the App. But App, by itself, is free to use.

What price should I enter then ?

Or is it Free ?

Comment: it is a free app not paid

Comment: you must select "free app"

Comment: Guys, thank you, but it would be more helpful to see link(s) to the source of information. This is serious matter, since it will be big hassle to change it later from Free to Paid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a programming issue.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#decide-price is some link. The 2 relevant rules are "free apps must remain free." & "you can change it at any time to be a free app but cannot then change it back".

Comment: @zapl you reply is the most relevant. You should make it the separate answer to be selected as the most helpful. Thanks )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between *paid* and *free* is at the time of installation. Do you have to pay **to install** the app or can you download it for free. In other words, does the button in the store say "buy" or just "install"?

It does not matter whether the app has in-app purchases (1) or ads later on. Both free and paid apps can have that but most app that rely on subscriptions and in-app purchases will be free.

The official developer's guide explains it here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373

For an overview of all the monetization options check out the course linked on https://play.google.com/console/about/guides/monetize/

The important points for the decision:

- Paid apps are not available everywhere. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286 for a list of countries and limitations.
- Paid apps cannot be set to a price of 0. This means no "This week free" type of promotion. There is in fact a minimum price you can set.
- Paid apps can be converted to free apps but never back. Whether existing customers will like you for that or how you could compensate them is a different question.
- Free apps must stay free forever. You can only unlist them and publish them under a new name.

(1) Some regions do make a difference between free apps with in-app purchases and free apps without them when it comes to availability. Basically, Google will not let you download an app with in-app purchases when they can't sell you those in-app purchases in that country.

Answer (score 3):

It's like this:

**Free:**  Completely free.  No cost to download.  You can still run ads, if you wish.   You can, also use IAP here, if you'd like.

**In App Purchases:**  Means that the user can pay money for things within the app.  Upgrades, level unlocks, subscriptions, things like that.  Your app can be free, but still have this option.

**Paid:**  You are charging people to download the app.  $.99 is the USD minumum.  You can, also us IAP here, if you'd like.

In other words, you can combine Free/Paid and In App Purchases, if you wish.  But free to download, still means free.

Comment: There is no such option as "In app purchases". Only Paid/Free. So does "In app purchases", like subscription, mean Paid or Free ?

Comment: Sorry, yes...  In App is a separate option.  In your case, the app is free.  This is because it's free to download.  The in app purchases are the option just underneath that.  And it will show that in the Store.  I clarified my answer a bit.